# Update multiple rows with random timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to update multiple rows of a column with random timestamp  but again 
all of the rows are getting updated with the same timestamp.

```
UPDATE RCBDBA.RCORD_REC S  
   SET R_TMSTMP= (
    SELECT to_timestamp(sysdate-201)  
          + (dbms_random.value(1,8))
          + (dbms_random.value(0,31))
          + (dbms_random.value(0,24)/24)
          + (dbms_random.value(0,1440)/1440)
          + (dbms_random.value(0,86400)/86400) AS ran 
     FROM dual) 
 WHERE S.WS_ID IN (
   SELECT S.WS_ID 
     FROM RCBDBA.RCORD_REC S 
    WHERE S.R_TMSTMP IN TO_TIMESTAMP ((
   SELECT scr.R_TMSTMP 
     FROM RCBDBA.RCORD_REC scr 
    GROUP BY scr.R_TMSTMP 
   HAVING COUNT(*) =177 )) )
```

Comment: why are you using IN and something else?

Comment: Because IN is not working with timestamp

Comment: I would suggest maken a cursor for your query. Then you use a for loop (for example: for rTable in cTable) to loop through that record. Then you loop through every row and you can update a column value.